# Image is displayed as low quality on android

Tags: android, image, android-4.4-kitkat

I am trying to insert my logo inside a main activity (log in screen) using ImageView widget. The problem I am having, when I have to select image from mipmap it selects the smallest image and once I resize to a bigger image it doesnt display image as sharp as it supposed to be.

My code inside ImageView:

```
android:layout_width="381dp"   
android:layout_height="139dp"   
android:id="@+id/logo"   
android:contentDescription="@string/logo"   
android:cropToPadding="false"   
android:contextClickable="false"   
android:src="@mipmap/logo"
```

I dont know why it uploads to bitmap and not to drawable, but when I upload an image I do it via Image Asset and it automaticly resizes to *hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi*

Any solutions of how to add a bigger image instead of resizing small image?

Comment: as a suggestion .9 patch logo may work here. Also you can try once with android:scaleType="centerInside"

Comment: i will try .9 patch as your other suggestion doesnt work (shows really tiny image)

Comment: No.. 9patch is just useless tool

Comment: lol... it is a very useful tool once you learn how to use it!

Comment: well but it is pointless in my situation as i made large and high quality image with no empty or wasted space, I dont need to crop or do anything like that. The case is that android studio doesnt use best quality image which was uploaded but takes smallest one for some reason

Answer (score 2):

Sorted. If anyone has the problem with image sizes, just copy an image and right click on drawable and select paste, it will paste the original image without resizing. Then in your ImageView select from drawable the image you pasted and it wil show big and sharp image

Comment: I am facing the same problem. I understand you somehow fixed. Could you please explain it a bit better - sorry, don't understand what you mean. Thank you.